# Как сохранить обработанную в цикле таблицу в этой же таблице?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть 28 датасетов, у каждого из которых нужно удалить столбцы с пропусками, переименовать столбцы, преобразовать числа записанные в object в float ну и умножить на 100. Проблема в том, что я создал функцию, в которой я выполнил вышеописанные действия и хочу пройтись циклом по списку dictinary, где хранятся все датасетов, но когда я выполняю цикл, новая таблица не сохраняется. Сам цикл работает, но на выход я получаю старую таблицу. Помогите пожалуйста, а то я уже 3 час сижу на этом.
пример датасета:http://www.minfin74.ru/opendata/7453136570-DeficiencyBudgetsMunicipalities/data-13-structure-1.csv
и еще: http://www.minfin74.ru/opendata/7453136570-DeficiencyBudgetsMunicipalities/data-4-structure-1.csv

```
def form(i):
    i = i.dropna(axis = 1)
    i.columns = ["id","name","money"]
    i["money"] = i["money"].str.replace(" ","")
    i["money"] = i["money"].apply(lambda x: float(x.split()[0].replace(",",".")))
    i["money"] = i["money"] * 1000
    return i 
#dataa = form(data_14_3)
for data in dictinary:
    data = form(data)
#print(dataa)
#print(data_14_4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for n in range(len(dictinary)):
    dictinary[n] = form(dictinary[n])
```

Comment: Все равно почему-то не работает, опять старая дата в результате.

Comment: В каком результате? У меня работает.

Comment: Я добавил скрин к вопросу, посмотри. Первый вывод - как выглядит типичная дата из тех, что у меня есть, второй - то, что я получаю, когда просто применяю функцию(это мне и нужно), третий - то, что я получаю после применения функции в цикле, как видишь таблица без изменений, столбцы не переименованы, тип данных не изменен.

Comment: Я мало что понял. Что такое data_2? И почему не устраивает второй вариант, если это то, что нужно?

Comment: Предлагаешь 28 раз вызывать эту функцию, в принципе неплохо, но я хотел автоматизировать этот процесс, поэтому и задал вопрос. Data_2 это один из датасетов.

Comment: Я не предлагаю, я пытаюсь понять. И сейчас понимаю ещё меньше, чем в начале.

Comment: Что именно вызывает у тебя вопросы? У меня есть 28 датасетов, у них у всех одни и те же проблемы, мне нужно от этих проблем избавиться, за этим я создал функцию, теперь я хочу автоматизировать её, посредством перебора списка переменных датасетов, и хочу сохранить этот результат в тех же самых датасетах. 2 вывод, где название столбцов: "id","name","money" - это то, чего я хочу, а другие выводы - это данные без обработки.

Comment: А в dictinary что?

Comment: Список, который хранит названия переменных датасетов.

Comment: я добавил csv файл, с одним из датасетов, если нужно.

Comment: Ну так список хранит "не названия переменных", а сами датасеты. И в цикле изменяются датасеты в списке. Выведи dictinary [3], например

Comment: Я знаю, просто не так выразился, прошу простить.

Comment: Я и говорю: после цикла новые данные хранятся в списке, а не в исходных датасетах (которые после создания списка уже никого отношения к ним имеют).

Comment: Да, теперь понятно, почему возникает такой казус. Спасибо огромное тебе. Жаль раньше вопрос не задал, сэкономил бы себе часов 6-7 жизни. Еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте читать данные так - тогда может не понадобится писать медленные функции:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data-13-structure-1.csv", sep=";", 
                 encoding="cp1251", thousands=" ", decimal=",")
```

результат:

```
In [113]: df
Out[113]:
     N Наименование муниципального образования  Дефицит / профицит (тыс. рублей)
0    1                        Верхнеуфалейский                      -37967.47000
1    2                          Златоустовский                      -41032.43000
2    3                             Карабашский                        4500.26000
3    4                               Копейский                       73151.82000
4    5                              Кыштымский                      -35021.72000
```

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали, насчет decimal и thousands, теперь будет меньше танцев с бубном)